# Getting the bundler gem execuble in $PATH

Tags: ruby, command-line, path, rubygems, bundler

I've installed Bundler 1.16.1 and am trying to configure my `$PATH` variable for using the `bundle` command. The [Bundler Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/doc/TROUBLESHOOTING.md) says:

> Note that you will need to append `~/.gem/ruby/<ruby version>/bin` to
>   your `$PATH` variable to use `bundle`.

I'm unable to locate the `/bin` executable. Here's the output of some troubleshooting commands on my system:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
$ which gem 
/usr/local/bin/gem
$ gem which bundler
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb
```

Also, `echo $PATH` reveals that `/usr/local/bin/gem` is in the `$PATH` already.

What's the path to the bundler gem executable then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the path to the bundler gem executable then?

It is listed in the documentation snippet you posted in your question as:

```
~/.gem/ruby/<ruby version>/bin
```

Note: replace `<ruby version>` with the library compatibility version (not the language version or the engine version!) of the implementation you are using.

Comment: OK, when I do `ls ~/.gem/ruby/`I get to directories: 1.8 and 1.9.1. Of the two, only 1.8 has a `bin` directory in it. So I've added `export PATH=~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:$PATH` to `.bash_profile`but still no effect.

Comment: Then it seems you installed your gems somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Running `gem environment` yielded this line, among others:

> EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/bin

From there, it was only a matter of adding the above path to the `$PATH` variable in `.bash_profile`.